# What's the maximum tire width of a Cannondale Bad Boy 6 2014?

Tags: tire, cannondale

A quite basic question; what's the widest tire that can be fitted to a Cannondale Bad Boy 6, 2014 (with a rigid Fatty fork)?
Would a pair of studded 40mm tyres (Suomi Tyres W240, 40-622) fit?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to test it out - theres enough variation in tires (esp. studded tires) for two tires to be marked the same size and one fit and one not fit.

This [thread](http://forums.mtbr.com/cannondale/questions-about-bad-boy-819282.html) indicates that for an older Bad Boy with rigid fork was able to clear a 47 mm tire (which looks to be the largest possible), so I'd guess the answer is yes, but YMMV.

Comment: Just because he got 47 mm on the bike does not mean there is enough clearance to ride it that way.

Comment: He says he has 3 mm clearance in that thread. With a 40 mm tire that OP wanted, even studded, should be pretty good.

Comment: 3 mm is enough to deal with wheel and frame flex?

Comment: It's going to be well bigger than 3 mm with a 40 mm tire than 47 mm tire. I prefer much bigger tire clearances in general.